My Discord bot doesn't send message when I type a command
I'm currently developing a Discord bot, but when I call the bot.process_command member function with several arguments, it does not respond and does not give an error message.
My code is as follows:
import discord  #Importation des paquets et des modules nécessaires au bon fonctionnement du bot
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents(messages=True, guilds=True)#intents enabling

class MyClient(discord.Client): #Connection message
    async def on_ready(self):
        print(f'Logged on as {self.user}!')

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$', intents=intents) #Setting command prefix

@bot.event #command function definition
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')

client = MyClient(intents=intents) #starts the bot
client.run('TOKEN')

I am testing the bot in an empty server with only the general channel. I already checked the Discord developer portal; the message intent is enabled.
I'm on Ubuntu 23.04 with python 3.8.0 installed in my venv with only discord.py package
Why isn't my Discord bot responding?

You define two discord.py clients, one being bot and the other client. bot has the event, but you start client, hence no response. If you use bot.run('TOKEN') instead, then the event will work and you will get response. Only use one instance of the discord.py client throughout your code.

You can remove client since bot can do everything client can, but easier. You can also use the bot.command() decorator to define commands easily. You only need to use bot.process_command() if you also have on_message().
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$",intents=intents)

@bot.command("hello")
async def hello(ctx):
   await ctx.send("Hello!")

bot.run("TOKEN")

